# Remove SearchBar text Underline in Xamarin Forms Android while focused/typing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, searchbar, custom-renderer

I want to remove the line that appears under the text (not `android:id/search_plate`) while focused/typing, I haven't been able to remove this.

- Is this possible?
- If possible, how could I do it?
- What should I read to learn to do this?

Context:

- we are talking about this:
  [image]
- Of course we are talking about a custom render here.
- What have I tried?

[SO Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582355/xamarin-forms-android-search-bar-remove-underline)

[SO Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845478/xamarin-remove-searchbar-underline-in-android)

What my code looks like:

```
   public class CustomSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
   {
       public CustomSearchBarRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
       {
       }

       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);

           SearchView searchView = Control;
           searchView.SetInputType(InputTypes.ClassText | InputTypes.TextVariationNormal);

           int textViewId = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
           EditText textView = (searchView.FindViewById(textViewId) as EditText);

           textView.SetBackgroundColor(G.Color.ParseColor("#FFFFFF"));
           textView.SetTextColor(G.Color.ParseColor("#191E24"));
           textView.SetHintTextColor(G.Color.ParseColor("#191E24"));
           textView.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 16);
           textView.SetPadding(8, 0, 40, 0);

           int searchIconId = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
           ImageView searchViewIcon = searchView.FindViewById<ImageView>(searchIconId);
           searchViewIcon.SetImageDrawable(null);

           int searchCloseIconId = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
           ImageView searchClose = searchView.FindViewById<ImageView>(searchCloseIconId);
           searchClose.SetPadding(8, 0, 8, 0);

           searchView.Iconified = false;
           searchView.SetIconifiedByDefault(false);


           //new code, did not work
           //this.Control.SetInputType(InputTypes.Null);

           //new code, did not work
           //GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
           //gd.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
           //this.Control.SetBackground(gd);

           //new code, did not work
           //var plateId = Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
           //var plate = Control.FindViewById(plateId);
           //plate.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);

           //new code, did not work
           //LinearLayout linearLayout = this.Control.GetChildAt(0) as LinearLayout;
           //linearLayout = linearLayout.GetChildAt(2) as LinearLayout;
           //linearLayout = linearLayout.GetChildAt(1) as LinearLayout;
           //linearLayout.Background = null; //removes underline
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That text underline is related to keyboard suggestion

```c#
Control?.SetInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions | 
                      InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword);
```

For some reasons the flag `TextFlagNoSuggestions` alone doesn't work, and needs to be combined with `TextVariationVisiblePassword`.

Comment: this is an excellent answer, just a note for future users reading this, you will lose the keyboard suggestions. for my use case is not worth it.